# Populating Google Maps for Rails markers based on geolocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to use the [Google Maps for Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem to populate a map with markers based on a custom gmaps4rails_callback that uses the current location, but I can't seem to get the code to replace the markers to trigger after the user's geolocation has been determined.

My `application.js` defines a custom maps callback function, along with a callback for `getCurrentPosition`:

```
function nearby_locations(position) {
    $.getJSON('locations/nearby.json',
          { lat: "33.7012", long: "-117.8683" },
          function(data) {
                    Gmaps4Rails.replace_markers(data);
          });   
}

function gmaps4rails_callback() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(nearby_locations);
}
```

For now, I'm using hard coded lat/long data, but eventually I'm going to key off of the real data in the `position` object passed to me. Running the getJSON call manually works fine, and my `locations/nearby.json` returns location data in the proper format that updates the markers as expected.

My view template just uses

```
<%= gmaps("map_options" => {"auto_adjust" => true, "detect_location" => true}) %>
```

Now I realize that I'm probably doing a geo lookup twice, by using both detect_location and then calling `getCurrentPosition`, but in a earlier attempt, code in `gmaps4rails_callback` was being executed before the geolocation permission from the browser (Safari) had even completed, so I thought this would delay execution until the location had been determined.

I've previously displayed a map without a custom `gmaps4rails_callback` and it worked fine, so I know my jQuery and JavaScript files are being included just fine.

Is it possible that Google Maps for Rails somehow already sets up its own `getCurrentPosition` callback and mine is being ignored? After adding some debug logging, it doesn't look like `nearby_locations` is called at all.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you set `"detect_location" => true`, this triggers the following function:

```
findUserLocation: function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
    //try to retrieve user's position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      //saves the position in the userLocation variable
      Gmaps4Rails.userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
           //change map's center to focus on user's geoloc if asked
            if(Gmaps4Rails.map_options.center_on_user === true) {
                Gmaps4Rails.map.setCenter(Gmaps4Rails.userLocation);
            }
    },
    function() {
          //if failure, triggers the function if defined
          if(this.fnSet("gmaps4rails_geolocation_failure")) { gmaps4rails_geolocation_failure(true); }
        });
  }
  else {
      //if failure, triggers the function if defined
      if(this.fnSet("gmaps4rails_geolocation_failure")) { gmaps4rails_geolocation_failure(false); }
  }
}
```

So yes the geolocation is already made... or in progress. This function is triggered **before** the `gmaps4rails_callback` but it's the tough part with browser geolocation: it takes an undefined time.

I thought about proposing a callback on failure but didn't think it was necessary to include a callback on success (I'm still not convinced).

Unfortunately, I don't understand the problem with your `gmpas4rails_callback`: I've both `detection_location`and callback and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what happens behind the scenes. I hadn't dug into the code when I posted my problem last night. Can you confirm if the execution of gmaps4rails_callback is blocked until both the user permission has been granted and the location has been determined (or the failure action triggered)? From my own testing, that didn't seem to be the case. I'll see about posting a quick project that shows off the problem that you can clone if you want a closer look.

Comment: The callback isn't blocked. I just added an alert in it and didn't answer chrome wish to geolocate my computer. The alert msg was displayed before I answered chrome.